# PHP while loop is infinite

Tags: php, while-loop

```
<?php
//Set up the base vars
$sceneCount=23;
$currentScene=1;
$brainBlownCounter=0;


//Assemble the scenes
while($currentScene <= $sceneCount)
{
    $scenes[] = 'Scene '.$currentScene;
}

//Make this film special
array_reverse($scenes);

//Play
$sceneCounter =0;
foreach ($scene as $somethingThatHappened)
{
    $sceneCounter++;

    $leonardsMemory = $somethingThatHappened;

    echo ('We see '.$somethingThatHappened.'<br />');
    echo ('Your brain is now '.(($sceneCounter / count($scenes) * 100)).'% blown.<br /><br />';

    $leonardsMemory=NULL;
}


//TODO: Remember Stanley Ipkiss
?>
```

Can anyone spot any problems in this code?

The while loop isnt acting as it should be and nothing gets outputted!

Thanks

Comment: -1??? why the vote down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment the value of currentScene

```
while($currentScene <= $sceneCount)
{
    $scenes[] = 'Scene '.$currentScene;
    $currentScene++;
}
```

and

Change this

```
foreach ($scene as $somethingThatHappened)
```

To

```
foreach ($scenes as $somethingThatHappened)
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
while($currentScene <= $sceneCount)
{
    $scenes[] = 'Scene '.$currentScene;
}
```

Both `$currentScene` and `$sceneCount` are not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
while($currentScene <= $sceneCount)
{
--->    $scenes[] = 'Scene '.$currentScene;
}
```

add a `$currentScene++` to move to the next value.